# multiple index to columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas:

```
(index) amount

0.0 0   73.74770979
0.0 1   34.36146516000001
1.0 0   25.759792399999995
1.0 1   117.37044276999995
```

I would like to have a DataFrame like this:

```
index  amount_0, amount_1
0.0    73....    34...
1.0    25....    117...
```

how can I do this. My index column consists of columns 'hour' and 'side'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `unstack()`. This allows you to specify which level of the index you wish to 'unstack':

```
df = df.unstack(level=1)
df 
             amount            
ind2          0           1
ind1                       
0.0   73.747710   34.361465
1.0   25.759792  117.370443
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `df.unstack(level=-1)` should do the trick.